# How can I implement in the Micorsoft Azure / Microsoft Synapse serverless SQL Pool service the Row Level Security feature on external tables?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, row-level-security, serverless-architecture

I am looking at a Data Lake csv file and want to create an external table in the serverless SQL Pool of Microsoft Synapse. The goal is to query this file with Row Level Security constraints in place.

When the external table is created on a dedicated Server, I am able to query the file with Row Level Security constraints in place.

How can I make the Row Level security for external tables on a serverless SQL Pool?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, row level-security is not supported in serverless SQL pool at the moment.

Can you please vote for this on our User Voice?
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse?category_id=171048

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the feature as it is. [T-SQL support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview#t-sql-support) on Serverless is limited.

E.g. `CREATE FUNCTION` [isn't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-sql-data-warehouse?view=azure-sqldw-latest).

> This syntax is not supported by serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics.

---

You could of course try to DIY using Views which are supported in Serverless.

- In the figure below Entitlements would become another CSV and EXTERNAL TABLE that you would create.
- You'll have to either find the right function to get current user and/or role for View's SELECT query, or provide it via some wrapper code from some other place where you maintain your own Context.

Disclaimer: I've not done this in Serverless so can't say for sure.

[image]